# How to modify the enchantement of an already enchanted item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if there was a way to add enchantments (using commands) to an already enchanted item. For example, I have a command that enchants an item if you have enough levels, but what if you get enough levels and you want to enchant it further, such as the item having protection I but the person wanting to upgrade to protection II or protection III? (I am making an zombie apocalypse map on vanilla and do not want to use mods.) Would there be a way to remove the enchantments and then add them back on the higher level?

Comment: Maybe the `/enchant` command would help?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, just enchant the item again with the already enchanted item on creative. You can't double enchant items in survival as far as I know, so this is the command;

```
/enchant (your username) (enchantment) (level)
```

Just do that twice, and you should be able to have two enchantments at once! (tested on 1.9)

Comment: This command doesn't expect a slot, as the enchantment is applied to the held item.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the item. For example:

```
/data merge entity @e[type=player] {ArmorItems:[{},{},{id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:protection",lvl:3s}]}},{}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use item modifiers for this.

This one removes all enchantments from an item:

```
{
    "function": "minecraft:set_nbt",
    "tag": "{Enchantments:[]}"
}
```

If you save this as a file named 'remove_enchants.json' in an item_modifiers folder in your datapack. You can remove the enchantments of an item being hold by a player with this command:

```
/item modify entity @s weapon.mainhand my_datapack:remove_enchants
```

Answer (score -2):

you don't need a command - just get each desired enchantment individually on separate tools/weapons/armor, then combine them with an anvil to get the combined enchantments.  you can also use enchanted books and combine them with the tool/weapon/armor with an anvil to get the enchantment you want.

i hope this helps!

Comment: OK. I was wondering if it was posable to do it thru commands. Is there a way to do it without an anvil?

Answer (score -3):

Use an anvil

1. Open Anvil
2. Add your item
3. put in the enchantment (I assume you are in creative)
4. Name the new weapon
5. Grab and Go

You can do the same with a command block but it is complicated. If I find my old auto enchant code I will post it. But don't hold your breath that was a long time ago.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question at all. Please re-read it. | btw, you're stating common knowledge.